# Hi why do I get problems with my elif and else in python?

Tags: python

Hi so I am just a beginner and was making some exercises and it marked my elif and else wrong with the error syntaxerror: invalid syntax.
Thanks in advance.

```
def lovefunc( flower1, flower2 ):
    if flower1 % 2 == 0 and flower2 % 2 != 0:
        print("true")
        elif flower2 % 2 == 0 and flower1 % 2 != 0:
            print("true")
            else:
                print("false")
```

I tried to make the indentations smaller etc. but all I tried didn't work

Comment: `if`, `elif` and `else` need to be at the same level.

Comment: its a indentation issue

Comment: You need to review your learning of `if/elif/else` syntax.

Comment: your function could be simplified as `print(flower1 % 2 != flower2 % 2)` (no need to use conditionals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your indentation.

```py
def lovefunc( flower1, flower2 ):
    if flower1 % 2 == 0 and flower2 % 2 != 0:
        print("true")
    elif flower2 % 2 == 0 and flower1 % 2 != 0:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Comment: Thanks mate. sorry if this was a dumb question but thanks

Comment: All of us were beginners once so don't feel bad about it!